# How to get information from child process

Tags: c, exec, parent-child

I want to write a program that does this command :

```
gcc -c file1 file2 file3 ...
```

The program must create child processes and every child will compile one file. I used this command in child process :

```
execlp("gcc","gcc","-c","-Wall",argv[i],NULL);
```

So far so good. The problem is if there are errors when compiling a file, the parent process must print the name of the file where there are errors. It's a condition that the parent which  will print the file name.

My solution is to create a table that contain child pid and the file name that it compile. The parent will wait its child to end. At the end of child we look if the child is terminated normally (it returned 0). If it's not we search in the table to find the file name that it processed by using his pid.

I'm searching for another solution. I don't know if there is a way to send the file name to the parent process. Of course we do that only if there are errors in that file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create a task queue.  i.e. create worker threads to accomplish some task, then leave.  If taht is the case, the approach is ***[described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern)***.

But your real question is about passing data back and forth between threads.  The function ***[CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*** includes a parameter, `LPVOID lpParameter`, which is included for just such an ability.  It is a void *, so it will accept any variable type, including a pointer to an array, a pointer to a struct, etc.  This allows you to pass as much or as little data back and forth as you need.

The code snippet below passes a a pointer to an array of data.  This will be the part interesting to you

Here is the section that creates the thread

```
    hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread( 
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size  
        MyThreadFunction,       // thread function name
        pDataArray[i],          // argument to thread function 
        0,                      // use default creation flags 
        &dwThreadIdArray[i]);   // returns the thread identifier
```

Look for the worker function `MyThreadFunction` that would receive and pass data:

***Here is the [complete, build-able code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***

***For posix***:

`pthread_create()` also contains passable data:
`int pthread_create(pthread_t * thread, pthread_attr_t * attr, void * (*start_routine)(void *), void * arg);`  in `void *arg`
Arguments can be passed to the thread using the last argument, just as in the windows version.  Also in play for what you want to do is a function `pthread_join()`, prototyped:
  `int pthread_join(pthread_t th, void **thread_return);`
This function is used as a *handler* upon the end of the thread that is called for (first argument thread handle). When thread exits, the last argument in pthread_join can receive data.  This data may be useful to your stated purpose.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that my program is in c not c++ and I must use the POSIX standard

Comment: Oh, That changes things, doesn't it?

Comment: @rabahRachid - Added some notes on POSIX.  `pthread_join()` passes `void **arg`.  Should provide method to do what you need.